# how to compare current row to another row

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

If the group has changed after incrementing the next group by 10 and after sequence wise flow updated.

My logic is compare the first row to another row, if the first-row match to another row that time incremented by 1 else does not match that time increment by 10.

```
  declare
          v_groupid varchar2(100);
          v_gameid varchar2(100);
          v_teamid varchar2(200);
          v_chest_no number;
          stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
    count1 number;
     temp number :=1;

         cursor c_stage is select distinct var_group_id from aokk_group_def where var_group_type='KR' 
         and var_group_category='T';
        begin
     -  open c_stage;
                 loop
                     fetch c_stage into v_groupid;

                     exit when c_stage%notfound;

                for i in (select distinct var_kalateamappreg_teamid,var_kalateamappreg_groupid from aokk_kalateamappreg_stage where
                    var_kalateamappreg_groupid between 'GR14' and 'GR17' order by var_kalateamappreg_groupid  )

                    loop

                    for j in (select distinct var_kalateamappreg_teamid,var_kalateamappreg_groupid from aokk_kalateamappreg_stage where
                    var_kalateamappreg_groupid between 'GR14' and 'GR17' order by var_kalateamappreg_groupid  )

                    loop


                      if (i.var_kalateamappreg_teamid=j.var_kalateamappreg_teamid) 
                       then 
                                UPDATE aokk_kalateamappreg_stage SET aokk_kalateamappreg_CHESTNO=temp
                                        WHERE  var_kalateamappreg_groupid=i.var_kalateamappreg_groupid and
                                         var_kalateamappreg_teamid=i.var_kalateamappreg_teamid; 
                                        temp:=temp+1;

                   elsif (i.var_kalateamappreg_teamid<>j.var_kalateamappreg_teamid) 
                               then 
                                UPDATE aokk_kalateamappreg_stage SET aokk_kalateamappreg_CHESTNO=temp
                                        WHERE  var_kalateamappreg_groupid=i.var_kalateamappreg_groupid and
                                         var_kalateamappreg_teamid=i.var_kalateamappreg_teamid; 
                                        temp:=temp+10;
                          end if;

                   end loop;
                      end loop;
                  end loop;

                 close c_stage;
     end;
```

I updated group id in my table but they have not properly updated.

Output:

```
VAR_KALATEAMAPPREG_TEAMID VAR_KALATEAMAPPREG_GROUPID AOKK_KALATEAMAPPREG_CHESTNO 
281 GR14 43285 
283 GR14 43336 
267 GR14 43183 
249 GR14 43132 
248 GR14 43081 
247 GR14 43030 
240 GR14 42877 
244 GR14 42928 
238 GR14 42826 
280 GR14 43234 
320 GR14 43387 
246 GR14 42979 
239 GR16 43538 
326 GR16 43689 
270 GR17 43839 
273 GR17 44121 
271 GR17 43980
```

Expected output:

```
VAR_KALATEAMAPPREG_TEAMID   VAR_KALATEAMAPPREG_GROUPID  AOKK_KALATEAMAPPREG_CHESTNO
238 GR14    42826
240 GR14    42827
244 GR14    42928
246 GR14    42929
247 GR14    42930
248 GR14    42931
249 GR14    42932
267 GR14    42933
280 GR14    42934
281 GR14    42935
283 GR14    42936
320 GR14    42937
239 GR16    42948 Increment by 10
326 GR16    42949
270 GR17    42950 Increment by 10
271 GR17    42951
273 GR17    42952
```

If group has changed after chest no has also incremented by 10.

Comment: Your code does not contain a `COMMIT` statement. You need to commit the changes to the database so that other sessions can see them.

Comment: now I  put commit  and output will be wrong show

Comment: Please explain the expected output as it's inconsistent. The change at group14 to group16 increased the chest by 10 (as expected by description). But the change at group16 to group17increased chest by 11. So if another group existed (say group 20) would the chest increase by 10 or 11 or perhaps 12 (due to +10 for group change + 2 for prior group changes). Your posted data appears to depend on being sorted by group but initial try doesn't enforce that. Is that required? Finally, what would be the results if the rows with team id 210 and 271 were reversed (no enforces sort on these either)?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid PLSQL and use `merge` with recursive query, where counter is increased by one or ten (plus one), depending on group change:

```
merge into stage
using (
    with 
      d as (
        select teamid, groupid, chestno, 
               row_number() over (order by groupid, teamid) rn 
          from stage where groupid between 'GR14' and 'GR17' ),
      c(teamid, groupid, rn, newchestno) as (
        select teamid, groupid, rn, chestno from d where rn = 1 
        union all
        select d.teamid, d.groupid, d.rn, 
               c.newchestno + case c.groupid when d.groupid then 1 else 11 end
          from c join d on d.rn = c.rn + 1 )
    select * from c) r
on (stage.teamid = r.teamid and stage.groupid = r.groupid)
when matched then update set chestno = newchestno
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e06acedadcb148e00f0250af6166c23c)</sup>**

Link with examples: [Recursive Subquery Factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2)